# What if the ball hits somebody in the head in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Not too long ago, a cricketer died as the ball hit him in the neck..

So how come there isn't anything between the stands and the sportsmen in cricket, a net or something similar? When somebody hits a 6, it usually lands right in the middle of the crowd. Why doesn't it hit people? Why are the accidents so rare? Are people really just that aware of where the ball is at any given moment?

Comment: During a test match, India vs England, Headingley (2002) Sourav Ganguly hit a six, a spectator trying to catch it was hit on the head so bad, his head was full of blood. Though he was taken to medicos and wasn't a fatal/much serious injury.
So yes spectators too get injured

Comment: There are specific wavers you actually agree to when you buy cricket tickets that removes the liability of stray cricket balls from sport organisers problems.

Answer (score 3):

People in the stands do occasionally get hit by the ball - as they do in soccer, baseball and any number of other sports.

Accidents are rare because it's a big hit to land a ball into the stands, although it's by no means unusual. When it happens it's a big deal, and so yes, people are more aware of the ball.

The cricketer who died was [Phillip Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillip_Hughes) - he was hit by a bouncer bowled at him, not by a ball hit at him by a batsman.

Comment: There was a case of a little girl who was hit by a ball hit by Chris Gayle in an IPL match in Bangalore.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously accidents happens some times in cricket not only the players. it happens to the audience too.i did a bit of search.take a look at the following links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2-yA-G5Wjo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcIVdGP17Qo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gVQfvJlMnM

and sometime it happens to the on field umpires too..

http://www.espncricinfo.com/other/content/story/805703.html

The following is a list of notable cricket players who died while playing a game, died directly from injuries sustained while playing, or died after being taken ill on the ground.

[image]

Always be aware of the ball if your in the ground...